# PowerShell font deploys for 1809

Tags: powershell

With the 1809 user font support in outlined [here](https://thewincentral.com/windows-10-redstone-5-version-1809-all-changes-new-features-so-far-categorized-changelog/) and [here](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/06/27/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17704/) the method I've used in the past for doing administrative installs of fonts no longer functions, instead installing the font only for specific account the install is run under.

It's a pretty standard PS script, based off one from the powershell gallery.

```
$ShellAppFontNamespace = 0x14
...
$ShellApp = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$FontsFolder = $ShellApp.NameSpace($ShellAppFontNamespace)
foreach ($Font in $Fonts) {
    Write-Host ('Installing font: {0}' -f $Font.BaseName)
    $FontsFolder.CopyHere($Font.FullName)
    break 
}
```

Is there some specific flag for copyhere I need to set to indicate this is a system wide command now? As it stands now it looks totally undocumented.

Edit:

I think that this is pointing properly to the C:\Windows\Fonts folder.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $FontsFolder.Self


Application  : System.__ComObject
Parent       : System.__ComObject
Name         : Fonts
Path         : C:\Windows\Fonts
GetLink      :
...
```

Comment: You are right it's not documented. Does the script make $FontsFolder equal to C:\Windows\Fonts ? if so, can you compare the security on the new files copied there, to be sure they inherit the folder security. I wonder if the file security just allow the user that runned the script, and not everyone else on the PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that's dealing with this issue I found the resolution. 
Effectively the shell path / variable 0x14 is being overloaded and redirected to the user's profile without a clear way to change this behavior. The `CopyHere` command as a result fails to save to C:\Windows\Fonts, and is shimmed over to the user's profile directly.

Avoiding the use of shell variable, copying the file by hand and adding the registry key by hand works as it should. I [packaged up an updated version](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/trbdk3-Install-Fonts) on the powershell gallery if anyone needs it.